# Circle: window.history.back() and location.back()

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, browser-history

In my Angular app, I have a view and a edit view with a input form.
The problem is:

If I use the browser's back button, window.history.back() or the equivalent location.back() in Angular2 **once**, it will work fine as expected.

But if I trigger successive (two times) the browser's back button, window.history.back() or the equivalent location.back(), it will start a circle - meaning returning to the initial site.

Another strange behavior with the same sites is:

1. From the view I go to edit view with normal
   this.router.navigate(['/edit']);
2. location.back() to go back to view
3. I go again to the edit view with normal
       this.router.navigate(['/edit']);
4. Now I have to trigger three times
       location.back() to go back to view.

The history seems to be corrupted.

Does anybody have a idea what the problem could be. Is it possible that it correlate with the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not import **routing** multiple times.

*export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes)*

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue while migrating from rc4 to final and here's what worked for me. As stated on a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40051123), you should export routes that belong to the main app module only once with the RouterModule.forRoot() method.

`export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(MainModuleRoutes);`

However, if you have child modules imported in your main app module that have their own routes, you should export them as child routes with RouterModule.forChild().

`export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(ChildModuleRoutes);`